# Setting char to all true bits

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-or

I am trying to set all bits in a char to true.

```
char foo = 00000000;
foo |= 11111111;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { //prints out bitwise
    printf("%d", !!((foo << i) & 0x80));
}
```

When foo is all 0, I get 11000111.
When foo == 00000110, it prints 11001111;
What is going wrong here?

Comment: `11111111` is a *decimal* constant.

Comment: I find `unsigned char foo = -1;` to be pretty reliable. And I suggest you too stick to unsigned types for bitmasks.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would prefer to work with `unsigned char` and use `UCHAR_MAX`...

Comment: @EugeneSh. - `-1` is less typing though :P

Comment: 0xFF............

Comment: In gcc you could do it as `foo |= 0b11111111;`, which is in the spirit of your original code, but it's non-standard (who cares though if you're not a language-lawyering nerd).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number `11111111` is a decimal constant, not binary.  Although you can use octal or hexadecimal constants, there are no binary constants (at least not standard ones).

If you want a number with all bits set, just apply the bitwise complement operator `~` to 0:

```
unsigned char foo = ~0u;
```

Comment: Just don't use `~0u` if the target variable is larger than unsigned int.

Comment: `foo = -1;` will do as well

Comment: Or if you know the bit size of your target variable then you can write it like: `uint8_t foo = 0xFF;` or `uint16_t bar = 0xFFFF;` etc, which I think is a bit clearer.

Comment: @GrahamS Macros exist like `uint32_t bar =  UINT32_MAX`  which is clear and not as error prone as `uint32_t bar =  0xFFFFFFF;`

Comment: @chux yeah that makes sense when you get to 32-bit and beyond. Saves counting those Fs. :)But most of the time I’m bit-bashing I’m working with 8 or 16 bit registers

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char foo = ~0u;`, is well answered by [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694903/2410359) and works well for:

1. `unsigned char`
2. `char` that is *unsigned*.
3. `char` that is *signed* and has the *usual* implementation defined conversion behavior.

`char foo = ~0u;` invokes implementation defined behavior (C111 6.3.1.3 3) of setting an out-of-range `unsigned` to `char` when `char` is *signed* and may not result in an all-ones bit pattern.

---

<strike>First consideration: Recognize that on rare platforms an all-ones `char` is a trap expression.  We will assume that is not the case here.</strike>

Note that with a rare sign-magnitude encoding, an all ones bit pattern for `signed char` does not convert to an all ones bit pattern as an `int`.  This may impact coding goals.

---

If code wanted to directly initialize a `char` (either  *signed* or *unsigned*) and not worry about conversion implementation defined behavior,  nor rely on encoding as 2's complement, 1's complement or sign-magnitude nor range nor `CHAR_BIT` value.

**compound literal**  C11

```
char mx1 = ( union { unsigned char uc; char c; } ) { .uc = -1u } .c;
```

**union**

```
const union {
  unsigned char uc;
  char c;
} ones = { -1u };
char mx2 = ones.c;
```

**or**

```
// (-1 | -2) is a one's complement all one bits      
// -1 is the two's complement all one bits  
// CHAR_MIN is the sign-magnitude all one bits  
char mx3 = (-1 | -2) | -1 | CHAR_MIN;
```

This  is a bit tricky to determine the *or* values on non-2's complement, but by analysis it works.

**~0**

```
// This may not work on rare sign-magnitude as it invokes implementation defined behavior
char mx4 = ~0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse the decimal `0` and `1` with binary `0` and `1`. When you assign `11111111` to `foo`, it is a decimal base literal and not a binary literal. In fact, there is nothing like binary literal as per C standard. Though, some compiler supports it as an extension. If you want to set a `char` to all true (`1`) bits, you can do it like this:

```
foo = ~(foo & 0);
```

Comment: Why do the `foo & 0` part? Why not just say `0`?

Comment: @GrahamS `foo` and `(foo & 0)` may have different result types.  Unsure how one benefits over the other in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting char to all true bits

```
#include <limits.h>
char all_ones = CHAR_MIN | CHAR_MAX;
```

Works correctly under all  `char` bit width, `char` sign-ness and integer encodings<sup>1</sup>.

---

`char` may be *signed* or *unsigned*,  If *signed*, it may encode as 2's complement, or rarely one's complement or sign-magnitude. [Examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table). It has at least 8-bits but on select platforms it is wider.  There are no padding bits.

In essence, we are looking for

```
char ones = CHAR_MAX;  // `char` is unsigned
char ones = -1;        // `char` is signed and 2's complement
char ones = ~0;        // `char` is signed and 1's complement (rare)
char ones = CHAR_MIN;  // `char` is signed and sign-magnitutde (rare)
```

Solutions that assign an out-of-range value to a `char` that is *signed* invoke *implementation defined behavior*.  So the result may be something other than the desired all ones.

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  C11dr §6.3.1.3 3

```
// Almost always correct alternatives
char all_ones = ~0; // Work great but maybe not on rare sign-magnitude per 6.3.1.3 3
char all_ones = ~0u; // Always invokes 6.3.1.3 3 when char is signed.
```

---

<sup>1</sup>On the rare *one`s complement* system, an all ones bit pattern may be a -0 or a trap.  When a trap, no solution is acceptable.